# Sending data from file to kafka topic using springboot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams

I want to send data from file in real time using kafka and springboot, I have tested this code to send data to kafka topic in JSON format using postman.

```
    @RestController
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProducerService kafkaProducerService;

    @PostMapping("/post")
    public void order(@RequestBody Order order) {
        kafkaProducerService.send(order);
    }

}
```

In may case I want to send data from file using springboot.
Any idea about how it can be done?

Comment: What does it mean for you sending data from file in real time? Send bytes? Or send part of json string?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

After the appropriate configuration in the `.propreties` and `pom.xml` i was able to use it in my service layer.

```java
private final static String TOPIC = "TOPIC";

@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, Sting> kafkaTemplate;

public void someMethod(){
    
    //... code
    
    kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, obj.toString());
}
```

I needed to send string and it works fine, hope it helps.
Also i made scheduled method to send on a Kafka queue programmatically.

You should also add to your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

That it's what i needed i my .properties

```
# Required connection configs for Kafka producer, consumer, and admin
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers=server
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   required username=''   password='';
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL

#Serialization
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

# Best practice for higher availability in Apache Kafka clients prior to 3.0
spring.kafka.properties.session.timeout.ms=45000
```

Let me know if that helps or needed something else

Comment: Can you give me more details please or any resources because I don't have any idea?

Comment: I have alerady added spring-kafka in pom file

Comment: i'm not sure about properties, was using a confluent cloud that works with kafka and needed different but all can be genereted by it --> https://confluent.cloud/login